Why does the energy of a wavefront stay constant in case of spherical waves?
The Energy content of a wavefront in case of a spherical wave emerging from a point source remains constant.Which essentially means that the energy present in a spherical shell of width $dx$ around a particular wavefront stays constant as the radius of the wavefront increases. My question is why that should be true?

It is more like, what else do you think it could have behaved like?

I don't know.Can you suggest something?

I would think they meant energy in the total wavefront ...i.e. the total sphere.  As the sphere gets bigger the area is bigger and the energy per area is smaller.

Energy does not disappear. Matter waves are energy transfers without matter transport in the direction of propagation. However, the molecules of the carrier substance are moving. They oscillate longitudinally or transversely to the direction of propagation. In a model of lossless oscillations, the energy content is constant at any distance from the source of oscillation as described by you. In reality, however, dissipation processes occur. This means, for example, that the sound wave always has a loss-causing proportion of transverse dissipation.
Only electromagnetic waves in a vacuum suffer no losses. This is due to the fact that the wave consists of photons which, between their emission (on the surface of the radio antenna) and their absorption at an obstacle, are not subject to any interaction - neither with each other nor with the environment. However, at a sufficiently large distance from the source, only discrete parts of the wave - namely individual photons - are registered. But in principle, even at such distances, the energy content in a shell remains unchanged.

Special spherical waves remain concentrated to an expanding 2-sphere in euclidean $\mathbb R^3$ only for waves without dispersion, that is the phase velocity is independent on the wavelength.
The only real waves of this type are light waves. But light waves are not spherical, they have dipole or higher multipole characteristics.
Normally, e.g. in dimension 2, there is always wave diffusion, that is, a wave emerging from a point source propagates inside an expanding cone
$$|\vec x | < c t $$
where $c$ the maximal group velocity, and the complete inner is filled with circles as we know in 2D from water waves.
Only in dimension 1,3 the spherical wave equation can be reduced to a flat 1D equation with a sharp wave front. In order to get rid of the first derivative when scaling the wave function by a power of $r$ in the $n$-dimensional radial part of the Laplacian, one has
$$\frac{\partial_{ct,ct} f(t,r)}{\partial t}  = r^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\cdot r^{1-n}\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^{n-1} \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^{-\frac{1}{2} (n-1)} f(t,r)\right)\right) $$ $$ f^{(2,0)}(t,r)=f^{(0,2)}(t,r)-\frac{n^2-4 n+3}{4 r^2}\cdot f(t,r)$$
The f-dependent term is vanishing only for $n=1$ and $n=3$.
In other words, light of a lightning has a constantly expanding wave front on a sphere in 3D only. This sphere is a ramdom mix of dipole waves.
The acoustic thunder comes in a thin 2D plane of the air with thickness of some acoustic wavelengths. It has its roll by wave diffusion for some seconds inside the wave front time-space-cone.
